# Callback function terminates outerloop

Tags: javascript

```
var items = ['1', '2', 'callback', '4'];

var testCallback = function (item, items) {
    var outputArray = [];
        if (item == 'callback') {
            for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            outputArray.push(testCallback('5', items));
            console.log(outputArray);
            };
        } else {
            outputArray.push(item);
        };

    return outputArray.join(',');
};

var testFunction = function (items) {
    var output = '';
    for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        console.log(i);
          output += testCallback(items[i], items);           
    };

    console.log(output)   
};

testFunction(items);
```

Here's example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9o57o9k1/).

I would expect output to be 125,5,5,54 (5,5,5,5 replaces 'callback'). But instead for statement (in testFunction()) terminates after 'callback' and does not proceed to last item in items[] and the output is 125,5,5,5.

Would appreciate any help. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `i` loop variable is global, and it's therefore shared in both functions.

Change each `for` loop as follows:

```
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/n5bo0nj1/)

The final output will then be `125,5,5,54` as expected.

Comment: @TinyGiant, I'm game!